# Filter/search emails in Microsoft Graph API by toRecipient and isRead

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

I'm trying to use the Graph API to find unread emails that were sent to xx@yy.com.

To find unread emails, I know I can use `$filter=isRead eq false`.

To find emails sent to xx@yy.com, I know I can use `$search="to:xx@yy.com"`.

I also know that `$filter` and `$search` cannot be used together. Is there any other way to find emails using both of these parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way seems to be to use the Microsoft Search API to search Outlook messages which provides more powerful way of searching messages similar to search in Outlook client.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "message"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "to:xx@yy.com isread:false"
            },
            "from": 0,
            "size": 25
        }
    ]
}
```

Resources:

[search Outlook messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-messages)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that there's a separate search endpoint. It probably won't work for me because it doesn't support delegated mailboxes, but is a good answer to the question.

Comment: Yeah, disadvantage of this search endpoint is that can access only the signed-in user’s own mailbox